# Cannot load OCI8 on an Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, php

I have installed the PHP OCI8 module using a guide [from this page](https://gist.github.com/mazedlx/8e7764dfe68f08168d3f66a60256a863).

But when I run my phpfile that has `oci_connect` it thrown out the page isn't working with error code "HTTP ERROR 500"

What did I do wrong? I tried the command `php -m`, and I found OCI8 there, and I tried `php -v` and I got no error at all, but when I tried running my PHP with something like `function_exists('oci_connect')` or `extension_loaded('oci8')` both give out false result.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Command line PHP is not the same as the Apache module for PHP. [Look at this answer for more info](https://superuser.com/a/971900/167207). If you don’t have the OCI8 module enabled for the web module, you will get what you are getting. Also, that guide is for PHP 7.1 as incited here: `/etc/php/7.1/mods-available/oci8.ini` Did you add that `extension=oci8.so` to the proper `php.ini` file? That PHP info webpage you have screenshots of should clearly show you which `php.ini` it is using. Just edit that and add the `extension=oci8.so` line and restart Apache to see the module come up.

Comment: I've put extension=oci8.so to every php.ini file(included that inside apache2 and inside oci8.ini inside mods-available library), I've been trying for 1 week and the module just won't load at all

Comment: `I've put extension=oci8.so to every php.ini file` That sounds like panic and overkill. You only need to put that in the `php.ini` used by the PHP that is loaded. The 500 error in the case of OCI8 usually comes if the directory you decompressed the OCI8 library into (`/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2`) doesn't exist or the permissions to that directory are off and Apache cannot read that directory. Look in your Apache error logs located  in `/var/log/` to see if you can get any clues as to what might be happening.