# Compiled a PHP, how do I load it in Apache?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, php

I compiled and install PHP7.1.7 from source on Ubuntu16. I followed this tutorial:
http://www.shaunfreeman.name/installing-php-7-on-ubuntu-16-04/

I followed it upto the place he adds something to the modules.ini files.

Now, Apache was not loading any php, so I installed

`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php`

Now apache loaded PHP, but the versions were different, and also did not have the PDO drivers I compiled with. I checked this using phpinfo()

Apache showed 7.0.18, while I installed 7.1.7. I don't know how this second version got installed (perhaps libapache2-mod-php ?)

Also the php executable in /usr/bin was 7.0.18, so I deleted that and created a symlink to my 7.1.7, so at least in the terminal the php works with the correct version.

I need to make Apache to work with this new version.

Things tried:

- Many other answers(like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/969861/phpinfo-and-php-v-shows-different-version-of-php) one) on the same issue said that I just needed to load the different module in my apache2 config. But I cannot find a module on my system that relates to the php7.1.7. I do have a php7.0, and I believe that is what apache is loading.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45313724/1030675

Comment: is that a problem if I post the same question on multiple sites? Besides I think this is a better place for it

Comment: Posting it without interlinking means you can get an answer somewhere, but people not attending the other site might still be working on a solution somewhere else, wasting their time.

Comment: ok, I did not know about that. So is there an expected way on how I should link the questions? Or just specifying a link works?