# Force Apache to use PHP 7.2 Debian 8

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, php, wordpress

I just updated PHP version from 5.6 to 7.2on my Debian 8 server,

On my info.php, i got :

```
PHP Version 7.2.14-1+0~20190113100657.14+jessie~1.gbpd8
```

On my server with php -v command :

```
# php -v
PHP 7.2.14-1+0~20190113100657.14+jessie~1.gbpd83c69 (cli) (built: Jan 13 2019 10:30:36) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.14-1+0~20190113100657.14+jessie~1.gbpd83c69, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

But, on my wordpress , I still have PHP 5.6 :

```
You are running WordPress 5.0.3 | PHP 5.6.30-0+deb8u1 | Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) | MySQL 5.5.54-0+deb8u1
```

I already have Apache restarted, but it does not support PHP 7.2.

Comment: PHP from the command line has nothing to do with the PHP module that Apache loads. To get Apache to use a specific PHP module you need to adjust your Apache’s config file; `httpd.conf` or `apache2.conf`. [More details here in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/971900/167207) on where to look.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the PHP version different in phpinfo() and CLI?](https://superuser.com/questions/971867/why-is-the-php-version-different-in-phpinfo-and-cli)

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have the apache2 php7.2 config files on your system:

```
# ls /etc/apache2/mods-available
```

You'll probably see (among many files):

```
...
php5.6.conf
php5.6.load
php7.2.conf
php7.2.load
...
```

If the php7.2.conf and php7.2.load files are present, then you can:

```
# sudo a2dismod php5.6
# sudo a2enmod php7.2
```

And then restart apache, for example:

```
# sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: More info in: https://superuser.com/a/971895/495739 by JakeGould